# If a coin is flipped 10 times, what percentage will start with heads

Tags: probability

If a coin is tossed 10x, out of all the possibilities, what percentage will start with heads?

Comment: Um, 50? $$$$  $$  $$$$

Comment: Well begun is **half** done !

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you ignore the "land on its edge" cases, the answer is 50%.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a fair coin, then there are $2^{10}$ possible outcomes.
However, if the string of outcomes must start with a head, then there are $1\cdot 2^{9}$ such outcomes. Hence, we have
$$\frac{\text{#Start with head}}{\text{#Possible outcomes}} =\frac{2^9}{2^{10}} = \frac{1}{2}. $$
So, $50\%$ of all possible outcomes start with heads.

Comment: While correct, this is harder than necessary.  We don't care about the lips after the first.

Comment: @RossMillikan Hahaha, I knew someone would say this. Yes, I know, but the other answer had no details. I wanted to include some substance. Thanks.

Comment: @Ross Millikan - I had many girlfriends and I do care about the lips after the first.

Comment: I think the details that are useful to add to the other answer would be clarifying that we do not care about later flips (not lips, as in my previous comment).  This would be useful if the same question came up with 11 flips, because we wouldn't have to redo it.  We should ignore what we do not need to worry about.

Comment: @RossMillikan I agree, but my assumption is that OP did not know "how to start", and so I gave OP something to work with. I leave it up to OP to develop their sense of what does and does not matter. So if OP had to redo it for 11 flips, then I would hope that he/she has that "A-ha!" moment and notices that indeed we only care about the first flip. If they gave some inkling that they understood what to do, then my response would have been "Notice that the we only care about the first flip....".

Comment: @RossMillikan and if we care about the lips after n, then we care about them after n+1. (Now you do the math.)

Answer (score -1):

If you mean heads plural then I would say $25$% cuz you have to get the first $2$ heads and that is $1/4$ chance.  The other $8$ don't really matter.

Comment: A single flip comes up heads or tails.  The s on the end is not a plural and does not imply two flips.